# Perl: modify an ImageMagick object in a subroutine

Tags: perl, reference, imagemagick, subroutine

I'm using Perl (5.16) and ImageMagick (6.8.8). I'd like to send a new ImageMagick object to a subroutine by reference and modify the object there, but I get "Can't call method "Read" on unblessed reference". Obviously, I'm not treating the object properly in the subroutine. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
my $im=Image::Magick->new;
ModifyImage(\$im,$f);

sub ModifyImage  {
    my $im=shift;
    my $file=shift;
    my $res = $im->Read($file);
    warn $res if $res;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Image::Magick` object `$im` already holds a reference to the data. You don't need to take a reference to the variable, and your call should look like

```
ModifyImage($im, $f);
```

And I would write the subroutine like this

```
sub ModifyImage {
    my ($im, $file) = @_;

    my $res = $im->Read($file)
    warn $res if $res;
}
```

to make it more concise, and to make it clear that `$im` and `$file` are parameters.